# apex charts how to add border radius to donut chart series

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I'm working on a donut chart using Vue apex charts and i'm trying to make the edges of each series/bar rounded as in the image below

[image]

but i can't find a way to add border radius to the series/bars, how can i do that?
what i'm getting is something similar to what we have in this [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-interview-ru2pp?file=/src/components/Chart.component.vue)

example code:

```
<template>
  <div class="example">
    <apexchart
      :width="width"
      :height="height"
      :options="options"
      :series="data"
    ></apexchart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueApexCharts from "vue-apexcharts";

export default {
  name: "Chart",
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
    },
    width: {
      type: Number,
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
  },
  components: {
    apexchart: VueApexCharts,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    options() {
      return {
        chart: {
          type: "donut",
        },
        title: {
          text: this.title,
          align: "left",
          style: {
            fontSize: "30px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            donut: {
              labels: {
                show: true,
                total: {
                  show: true,
                  label: "Total",
                  fontSize: "22px",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  color: "black",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
        colors: [
          "#0066a4",
          "#0096f0",
          "#80c5fd",
          "#e2e2e2",
          "#a9a9a9",
          "#393939",
        ],
        noData: {
          text: this.loading ? "Loading..." : "No Data",
        },
        labels: [
          "Restobar Digital",
          "Campus Digital",
          "Metrovision",
          "Billboard",
          "Street Column",
          "Bus Shelter",
        ],
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately apexcharts doesn't provide any [options in its API](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/pie/) that could create such an effect.  The progress bars that make up the chart are also drawn as SVGs so there's no CSS you could use to affect the shape. You would have to find another library that can do what you want or roll your own solution